# In TFS, how can you write a query offset a date by a separate field?

Tags: tfs, wiql

In TFS, you can set up a work item query with a date offset like

```
Date > @Today - 7
```

Is is possible to use another field as the offset instead? Like, say you have [CustomOffset] that is an Integer. Is it possible to do something to the affect of:

```
Date > @Today - [CustomOffset]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, you can add the due date column on a query and see the results.
[image]

However, what you want to achieve it's not able through the build-in query for now. As you said, the value could only be an integer. And you need to manually type the integer. TFS will not automatically capture the `Customoffset` value from fields and calculate the  date.

Even though we do **not have an out of the box way** to do this, but I believe this could be achieved relatively easily in a extension. Through the API you could easily fetch the value of a specially filed, and use WIQL to generate a query, pass the value to the query, finally will get the result as your need.